# What Excel function to populate specific data from one excel tab to another based on a criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, tabs, microsoft-forms

I have created a Forms document that is linked to my excel spreadsheet. The information inputted within the form is populated within the excel document. Each line item entered will have an accounting code attached to that entry. I have added several tabs for each individual accounting code to track.

Each tab has the Date, description, Actual $, Forecast $ etc..

I am attempting to populate the information based on accounting code into the respective tabs. However, i am unable to find the appropriate excel function that will populate into the specific tab based off the accounting code. Each tab is for an individual code. I will add formulas into each tab linked to the one that brings info in from the forms.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: tried https://exceljet.net/index-and-match  ?

Comment: [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) may also be useful

Comment: Yes i have tried both and have had no luck with either. Thank you for the suggestions. I have added pictures and additional descriptions below

Answer (score 0):

[Main tab which collects the information inputted by the forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OkGk.png)

So this is the main tab which collects the information inputted by the forms.

[Tab specific to the accounting code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxamO.png)

I am trying to link as a specific code,in this case 4001 is entered it will be filtered by the formula to populate into the 4001 tab

Ive tried vlook and didnt seem to be able to get it to work. as well as Index/match. I am hoping to have the formula for each of the items such as date, actual. forecast, description be pulled in as the accounting code is referenced for that transaction